# How to Phi^-1 transform a variable in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models

I'm trying to create a Bayesian mixed linear model for my master thesis but having trouble with heteroscedasticity. So my supervisor suggested to Phi^-1 transform my dependent variable (since it's a continous variable between 0 an 1).
Since I just started learning R, I don't really know how to do this.

My model looks like this:

```r
model <- stan_lmer(y ~ x + (1+x|z), data = mydata)
```

I know that a log transformation would look like this:

```r
model <- stan_lmer(log(y) ~ x + (1+x|z), data = mydata)
```

But I can't find the function, that I need to Phi^-1 transform it...

All I found is the `Phi_inv()` function from the BayesianFROC package, which is no longer supported with the current version of RStudio. Maybe I'm also using the wrong search terms but I'm not that deep into statistics either (only 3 semesters).

Any suggestions? Thank you already!

Comment: `Phi` usually denotes the cumulative function of the standard normal distribution. Indeed `Phi^{-1}` maps the interval (0, 1) to the real line.

Comment: It's `qnorm()`, `Phi()` would be `pnorm()` (the CDF of the Gaussian distribution) and `qnorm()` is the inverse of the CDF of the Gaussian distribution.  You can see as much in the [online help file for `Phi_inv()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BayesianFROC/versions/1.0.0/topics/Phi_inv).  Likewise, in the [code](https://github.com/cran/BayesianFROC/blob/master/R/Phi__and__Phi_inv.R), you can see how they are defined.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, could you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Phi_inv()` function is the inverse of the Gaussian CDF.  This is already implemented in the `qnorm()` function in the `stats` package.  Likewise, `Phi()`, the CDF of the Gaussian distribution, is implemented in the `pnorm()` function in the stats package.  You can see as much in the [online help file for Phi_inv()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BayesianFROC/versions/1.0.0/topics/Phi_inv). Likewise, in the [code](https://github.com/cran/BayesianFROC/blob/master/R/Phi__and__Phi_inv.R), you can see how they are defined:

```r
Phi <- function(x) {
  y <- stats::pnorm(q=x)
  return(y)
}
```

and

```r
Phi_inv <- function(x) {
  y <- stats::qnorm(x)
  return(y)
}
```